# Eclipse not responding after accidentally deleting file on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse

I was in class and running some javafx programs. When the 'screen' was not yet created it opened new windows and they were not able to close. I ended up using 'find in folder' and deleted the "java" file which I ended up having someone send me the file (java.dms).  Ever since, eclipse does not respond. I deleted eclipse, re-downloaded it (neon), downloaded the newest eclipse (oxygen) and still not responding. It does not respond after any command, even just opening a new java project.

EDIT: I believe I found where the file came from. When in files and at Computer I went to (Untitled - Library - Java - JVM - jdk1.8.0_131.jdk - Contents - Home - bin) in this bin file is where I believe the original "java" file was. Even after downloading the new jdk there is still not a "java" file in this bin folder. Could this be why? If it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's Java that's broken, not just Eclipse. Did you try reinstalling your JVM?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing and installed the newest version and it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It did end up being the JDK. I had to find it within the folder and saw it was still missing the "java" file even after downloading it again off of the Oracle website. To find it in Folder, open folder and on the top bar click "GO" and then "Computer". From here, go into Untitled->Library->Java->JVM and the jdk folder is in here. For some reason it was the "jdk1.8.0_131jdk" and I installed the "jdk1.8.0_161jdk" which then had the "java" file. I reinstalled eclipse and everything worked again.